# How to return values from foreach function

Tags: wordpress, foreach, widget, return, shortcode

Im creating one widget for wordpress website and i need to get multiple values in function and return them with return function on website. If i dont use return code wont appear inside div's

Here is my code for widget

```
    if($tweets) : foreach($tweets as $t) : ?>
            <div class="vf-tweet">
                <img src="<?php echo $t['image']; ?>" width="36" height="36" alt="" />                
                <div class="vf-tweet-inner">
                    <?php echo $t['text']; ?> | 
                        <span class="vf-tweet-time"><?php echo human_time_diff($t['time'], current_time('timestamp')); ?> ago</span>
                </div><!-- /vf-tweet-inner -->
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <a href="http://twitter.com/#!/<?php echo $name; ?>">[ Follow us on Twitter ]</a>
    <?php else : ?>
        <p><?php _e('No tweets found.', 'vt-translate') ?></p>
    <?php endif;
```

and i need to return this by using return function but im little stuck i dont know how to deal with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to build a string with your required output and return that:

```
function function_name() {
    $str = "";

    if($tweets) : foreach($tweets as $t) : ?>
        $str .= "<div class="vf-tweet">";
        /** Do the same for the rest of the code above **/

    return $str;
}
```

Comment: I have been trying to wrap it in string but somehow i was making mistake somewhere so i tried to find another solution but no luck, thanks for posting your solution and making me to take another look into building string. Since widgets are wrapped in function i can't declare function again so i ended up with solution like below that works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if($tweets) : foreach($tweets as $t) : 
        $tweet_show .= '<div class="vf-tweet"><img src='. $t['image'].' width="36" height="36" alt="" /><div class="vf-tweet-inner">'.$t['text'].' | <span class="vf-tweet-time">'. human_time_diff($t['time'], current_time('timestamp')).' ago</span></div></div>';
        endforeach;
        $tweet_show .= '<a href="http://twitter.com/#!/'. $name .'">[ Follow us on Twitter ]</a>';
    else :
        $tweet_show .= '<p>'. __('No tweets found.', 'vt-translate') .'</p>';
    endif;

return '<div class="vf-tweets">'.$tweetstitle . $tweet_show .'</div>';
```